# AUTO addition in mysql using mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a column say `X` which is of type `double` . Is it possible to insert values into X like '3+4' so that it gets stored as 7 ? 
I was able to do so in earlier versions of mysqlWorkbench but since 6.3 i get error "`Data truncated for row..`"
The same works perfectly fine as expected if run the insert command through terminal. 
Is there some settings/flags to be set to work as expected ?
Thanks.

Edit: I tried to `set sql_mode =''` to suppress the error. The error was not there but the value got stored as 3 and not 7 .

Comment: Can you show your insert statement and you table structure?

Comment: Table is as: x(double) y(double) and insert is as: Insert into table values(3+4,4);